# openssl / valgrind

Tags: openssl, valgrind

I have an application that has to calculate the MD5 of file, I have
used the openssl library, valgrind complains about some blocks still
reachable.

Compile the following code:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
   BIO * mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
   BIO_vfree(mem);
   return 0;
}
```

the run it using valgrind this is what I'm obtaining:

```
==23597== 220 bytes in 6 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==23597==    at 0x4022D78: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
==23597==    by 0x432FD0D: (within /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x433036E: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x43989C9: lh_new (in /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x4332025: (within /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x433249B: (within /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x4332B5D: CRYPTO_new_ex_data (in /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x438E053: BIO_set (in /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x438E0E9: BIO_new (in /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==23597==    by 0x80485E1: main (in /home/kalman/cxx_test/md5test/a.out)
```

anyone had same experience ?

Answer (score 5):

OpenSSL has actions that confuse Valgrind when not compiled with -DPURIFY.  [Is this the error you are seeing?](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG14)

Comment: As an example of what happens when you don't use -DPURIFY, see http://www.metasploit.com/users/hdm/tools/debian-openssl/ (I'm not saying that running valgrind without -DPURIFY directly caused the bug, but it did cause people to take actions that ended up causing the bug). :-P

Answer (score 4):

I believe those are some static structures that openssl allocates.  I ran your code, and I ran the following code and valgrind reported that both had the same amount of unfreed memory:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
   BIO * mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
   BIO * mem2 = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
   BIO * mem3 = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
   BIO * mem4 = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
   BIO_vfree(mem);
   BIO_vfree(mem2);
   BIO_vfree(mem3);
   BIO_vfree(mem4);
   return 0;
}
```

~

Answer (score 4):

```
BIO_new() -> BIO_set() -> CRYPTO_new_ex_data() -> int_new_ex_data() -> def_get_class()
```

int_new_ex_data() do not release the mem that def_get_class malloced.

SEE: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/memory-leak-in-engine-cleanup-td30935.html
http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2673&user=guest&pass=guest

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL contains a lot of uninitialized variables, variables and memory never freed, variables never cleared and not reachable outside scope to even be freed manually. 
Valgrind finds a lot of these.

The PURIFY flag is only related to the rand()_function. So to avoid a detection in Purify Openssl actually uses different source code if that flag is set. Nice coding... Maybe better to fix the problem in first place?!

Comment: Can `valgrind` detect the OpenSSL Punycode CVE-2022-3602 issue? I tested in a small example of corrupted `memmove()` that `valgrind` can detect it. But in the case of `punycode.c`, in version `3.0.6` it failed to detect it. Any comments?

Comment: @daparic This is a different question...  Maybe make a new question? Include the code in punycode.c that you would expect Valgrind to detect...